# After uninstalling wine some of the free space is 'locked'?

Tags: wine, disk-usage

I have installed Wine just to play  with it (and installed a game that had approx 7-8 GB) and now I have uninstalled Wine and removed it configs and I am left with these 7-8 GB less free space than I had before.

I have no idea where this place evaporated since I had like ~~ 8 GB occupied (16 GB free) before the isntallation

This will maybe show you what I mean :

[image]

Comment: You should remove the .wine directory from your home folder completely. Type the following in terminal `rm -rf ~/.wine` and then check your disk usage.

Comment: I have removed that and still the same. Might this be an issue with mounting `.iso` file with `Gmount` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wine user prefixes are located by default at each user's home in `~/.wine`.

Remove that folder to take back the space Wine took when you installed Windows software.

To view the folder open `nautilus` navigate to your user's home and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<<kbd>h</kbd> to display hidden files/folders.

Comment: I already removed that and I still do not have this free space I should have. Maybe that's an issue with mounting the iso file with `Gmount` that I have used to install the game.

Comment: Then it is not Wine :/ Did you do anything else in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use Disk Usage Analyzer to find what is taking the space. Also, you can try using `locate` to find the Wine folder:

```
sudo updatedb
locate .wine
```

this should let you find the location of the .wine folder, then you can delete it.

Comment: I already did that. It's like the space is located somewhere on the disk but I have no clue where exactly.

Comment: that's weird... have you installed wine with apt-get or used other method to install it (like PlayOnLinux)?

Comment: I have installed it with `apt-get` ( and now reinstalled it from `1.4` to `1.5.10` from development branch)

Answer (score 1):

The top line in Disk Usage Analyzer is the root of the file system.  It literally contains everything on the hard drive, so it always reads 100% usage.  You are just misreading the display.

Comment: Ok, you are right but what I wanted to point out here is that the root file system has 5.9 GB and just above this there is a statement - `File system capacity 25.1GB, used 13.4GB`. So why here we have 5.9 and here 13.4 ?

Comment: By default "File system capacity" is showing several partitions attached currently to your machine. Go to Edit/Preferences and uncheck all partitions except root and you will see 5.9Gb reported in the top statement.